# Scala - How to convert from List of tuples of type (A,B) to type (B,A) using map

Tags: scala

What is the best way to convert a `List[String, Int]` A to `List[Int, String]` B. I wanted to use the map function which would iterate through all items in my list A and then return a new list B however whenever I apply the map function on the list A it complains about wrong number of arguments

```
val listA:List[(String, Int)] = List(("graduates", 20), ("teachers", 10), ("students", 300))
val listB:List[(Int, String)] = listA.map((x:String, y:Int) => y, x)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about this:

```
val listB = listA.map(_.swap)
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use pattern matching to get the elements of a pair. I swear a question like this was asked just a few days ago....

```
listA.map{case (a,b) => (b,a)}
```

Comment: +1: Jean-Philippe's answer gives arguably the best (shortest and most efficient) way to do the job, but this answer gives linuxlewis the missing clues to understand why the failed attempt failed.